# como eu faço para fazer um slideshow com divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

atualmente meu carrosel tem 3 divs, e eu gostaria que as divs transitassem do 1 para o 2 e do 2 para o 3 e do 3 para o 1 com um temporizador de 2 segundos, como eu faço isso? meu codigo está assim:

```
<div class="container">
             <div class="wall wall-1" id="wall-1";>
               <a href="#wall-3"><img src="imagens/setae.png" 
id="imgcarrosele"/></a> 
               <a href="#wall-2"><img src="imagens/setae.png" 
id="imgcarroseld"/></a>
             </div>

             <div class="wall wall-2" id="wall-2">
               <a href="#wall-1"><img src="imagens/setae.png" 
id="imgcarrosele"/></a>
               <h1>carrosel numero - 2</h1>
               <a href="#wall-3"><img src="imagens/setae.png" 
id="imgcarroseld"/></a>
             </div>
             <div class="wall wall-3" id="wall-3">
               <a href="#wall-2"><img src="imagens/setae.png" 
id="imgcarrosele"/></a>
               <h1> carrosel numero - 3</h1>
               <a href="#wall-1"><img src="imagens/setae.png" 
id="imgcarroseld"/></a>
             </div>
         </div>
```

css

```
  .container{
  width: 800x;
  height: 500px;
  margin: -20px auto 0px auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  }

  .wall{
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  }

  .wall-1{ 
 background-color: #f00;
 background-size: cover;
  }
  .wall-2{ background-color: #0f0;}
  .wall-3{ background-color: #00f;}

   .wall:target{
   display: block;
  }

  img#imgcarrosele {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      float: left;
      opacity: 0.3;
      margin-top: 200px;

  }

   img#imgcarrosele:hover {
      opacity: 1;
   }

    img#imgcarroseld {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      float: right;
      opacity: 0.3;
      margin-top: 200px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
   }

   img#imgcarroseld:hover {
    opacity: 1;
   }

  img#idimg {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  position:relative;
  }
```

Comment: Cara e como seria esse slideshow, apenas uma transição de uma imagem aparecendo por cima da outra? uma imagem andando para a esquerda e a outra entrando? vai ter seta para controlar ou vai ficar girando automaticamente?

Comment: seria o seguinte, a div container abrigaria 3 divs, a wall-1 2 e 3, o que eu quero fazer é a animação, do wall 1 passando pro 2, do 2 pro 3, e do 3 pro 1, a cada 3 segundos, passar de div para div, e embaixo um pager que se vc segurar o mouse encima ele mostre o wall respectivo dele (aquelas bolinhas que fica embaixo do carrosel)

eu ja tenho as setas para controlar, agora eu quero que passe automaticamente depois de 3 segundos

Comment: mas como seria essa transição entre as imagens? vc quer que uma aparece por cima da outra fazendo tipo um fade, ou que uma role para a esquerda enquanto a outra vem da direita tipo um carrocel?

Comment: que role pra esquerda